# Convert Sonicwall Export File to Plain Text

Tags: sonicwall

I want to convert Sonicwall Export File to Plain Text

I used: https://www.base64decode.org/dec/Z29iYmxlZHlnb29r/

and: http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

but still it is not full readable.

anyone know the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the string converted from that website doesn't split character "&" , you can save the string to .txt (assume it is SonicWALL.txt reside at c:\ ) file then use powershell.exe to make it more readable :

```
(get-content c:\sonicwall.txt) -replace "\&","`n"
```